# SSID not on list

Tags: networking, network-manager

I've updated my Ubuntu Mate to V16.04 with RJ45 cable, now I want to connect back my PI3 over my Wifi network but my SSID is not on the list .... Any idea ? I try many times to restart the network with the sudo dhclient wlan0 I get this answer : RTNETLINK answers: "Operation not possible due to RF-Kill" I'm lost ! 
Here a snap of my screen (sorry is in French),

[image: Snap of Wifi network, all over me visible but not my one]

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: So if you unplug your RJ45 your connection switches over to WiFi automatically? On my system Wired and WiFi are always simultaneously connected so I don't have this problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks ... I killed my Ubuntu Mate and replace it with Raspian (2019-09-26-raspbian-buster-full), all works fine, RJ45 connection and Wifi (my SSID is visible on the list).
Maybe this version of Mate are not tested or unstable .... too bad !

BTW how to mark the post UNSOLVED ?

By !